# Show image in slider Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi i use codeigniter to simple listing script. I have a multi images upload for each listing 5 images...
But i have a problem with showing in listing details page....

i have two tables `properties` and `media` In `media` has 3 column `id` `property_id` (same with `properties.id` and `photo` (this is image name + extension)

Controller: **Properties.php**

```
 <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Properties extends My_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Property');
}
public function details($slug){
    $this->data['listing'] = $this->Property->find_by_slug($slug);
    $this->load_theme('properties/details');
}

}
```

Model: **Property.php**

```
  <?php
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Property extends CI_Model{

var $table = 'properties';

function find_by_slug($slug){
    $this->db->select('properties.*,users.*,media.photo');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = properties.user_id');
    $this->db->join('media', 'media.property_id = properties.id');
    $this->db->where('slug',$slug);
    return $this->db->get($this->table,1)->row_array();
}
}
```

View: **details.php**

```
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                 <div class="item active">
                                        <?php $x = 0; ?>
                  <?php if($listing):?>
                <?php foreach ($listing as $m):?>
                <?php $x++ ; ?>
                                 <div class="item <?php if ($x == 1) echo 'active' ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo site_url('files/listing/'.$m['photo'])?>" class="thumb-preview" alt="<?php echo $m['alt'];?>">
                                    </div>

                 <?php endforeach;?>
              <?php endif;?>
              </div>
```

I can not understand why it does not show the images in the slider...

Comment: I think you have an extra item outside the foreach loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way you don't have to define $x to get index 1, you can do foreach($listing as $key=>$m) and use $key to get index

Comment: Nope, i try with $key but not work...

Answer (score 0):

If in config, `site_url()` can have `index.php` at the end. That will break your image url.

If you need to access your resources, always use  `base_url()`.

**Change:**

```
site_url('files/listing/'.$m['photo']);
```

**To:**

```
base_url('files/listing/'.$m['photo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it can not find the appropriate id